# PHP: display message if redirected from PHP file

Tags: php, session

I'm probably going about this the complete wrong way, but here's where I am at.
I have a page called adminquery.php and on it is a form. When that form is submitted, it calls a file called adduser.php
This page attempts to add the user sent by POST to a database and sends back one of two messages (added or updated) which should display on the adminquery.php page.

```
if ($row[0] == 1)
{
    //update
    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "user updated";
}
else
{   
    //add
    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "user added";
}
header("Location: adminquery.php"); 
die();
```

adminquery.php displays the message

```
        if(isset($_SESSION['errMsg'])){
            echo "<p>".$_SESSION['errMsg']."</p>";  
        }
```

So far, so good. However, when I reload adminquery.php or access it from another page, I want it to not display this _SESSION message which is no longer applicable.

So I thought I would check the originating page when loading adminquery.php and, if it's not been accessed from adduser.php I would empty the message

```
    $referringSite = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    if (strpos($referringSite, 'adduser') == false) {
        //$_SESSION['errMsg'] = $referringSite;
        $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "";
    }
```

The commented line is used to check the referring page and it displays adminquery.php as the referring page rather than adduser.php (which has been called but not displayed). It seems like unless the page has been displayed or an element on it clicked to reopen adminquery.php that it's not recognised as the referring page.

Is there some simpler solution I'm not seeing?

Comment: Could just remove/clear `$_SESSION['errMsg']` right after displaying it

Comment: Add `unset($_SESSION['errMsg']);` after `echo "<p>".$_SESSION['errMsg']."</p>";`

Comment: That was, in fact, ridiculously easy :) Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an empty string won't clear the session variable. You need to unset it like so:

```
unset($_SESSION['errMsg']);
```

Also, you don't need to check the referrer. Since the user script sets that variable, the admin query script can just check if it exists, and if so, remove it after displaying the appropriate message.

Answer (score 1):

You must unset this session variable.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['errMsg'])){
    echo "<p>".$_SESSION['errMsg']."</p>";
    unset($_SESSION['errMsg']);
}
```